# Angular: Where to find ngsw.json?

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I want to remove ngsw.json to deactivate ServiceWorker. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#fail-safe

I'm using Angular v7.

Where can I find this file?

Comment: Most operating systems have a feature that will allow you to search the hard drive. What OS are you running?

Comment: The problem is the file isn't available. I am not sure why. I did use OS to search for file.

Comment: I created a step by step Angular PWA tutorial, if you are interested: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular

Answer (score 0):

The `ngsw.json` file only adds customisation for service workers, it does not generate one itself. This instead is handled in the `angular.json`

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              ...
              "serviceWorker": false
            },
          }
```

If you add a service worker via `ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*` then the cli will automatically update this file, as well as generating the `ngsw.json` amongst other things. More info here: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#adding-a-service-worker-to-your-project